# Issues in android app getting a random number generated from spinner to enter into the textfield

Tags: android

I am having issues getting the random number to appear in the Textview please help.

```js
package com.example.diceapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Dice extends Activity {
 
 double random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.dice);
 final Spinner group = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
 Button roll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDice);
 roll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 final TextView result = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult));
 
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if (group.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("6 sided")){
    result.setText("random");
   }
   
  }
 });
}
}
```

If i missed any information that you might need please let me know as of this point it gets to the button to roll the dice and then nothing happens and i am not getting any errors.

Comment: I have been looking for a while but cant seem to get this to work any and all help is much loved.

Answer (score 0):

Change below line

```
result.setText("random");
```

To `result.setText(random);` to display the random number you generated.